# Mask from max values in numpy array, specific axis

Tags: python, numpy

**Input example:**

I have a numpy array, e.g.

`a=np.array([[0,1], [2, 1], [4, 8]])`

**Desired output:**

I would like to produce a mask array with the max value along a given axis, in my case axis 1, being True and all others being False. e.g. in this case

`mask = np.array([[False, True], [True, False], [False, True]])`

**Attempt:**

I have tried approaches using `np.amax` but this returns the max values in a flattened list:

```
>>> np.amax(a, axis=1)
array([1, 2, 8])
```

and `np.argmax` similarly returns the indices of the max values along that axis.

```
>>> np.argmax(a, axis=1)
array([1, 0, 1])
```

I could iterate over this in some way but once these arrays become bigger I want the solution to remain something native in numpy.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Method #1**

Using [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html), we can use comparison against the max values, while keeping dims to facilitate `broadcasting` -

```
a.max(axis=1,keepdims=1) == a
```

Sample run -

```
In [83]: a
Out[83]: 
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 1],
       [4, 8]])

In [84]: a.max(axis=1,keepdims=1) == a
Out[84]: 
array([[False,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

**Method #2**

Alternatively with `argmax` indices for one more case of `broadcasted-comparison` against the range of indices along the columns -

```
In [92]: a.argmax(axis=1)[:,None] == range(a.shape[1])
Out[92]: 
array([[False,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

**Method #3**

To finish off the set, and if we are looking for performance, use intialization and then `advanced-indexing` -

```
out = np.zeros(a.shape, dtype=bool)
out[np.arange(len(a)), a.argmax(axis=1)] = 1
```

Comment: I like the second one, ( `np.equal.outer(a.argmax(axis=1), range(a.shape[1]))`)

Comment: I ended up using a variation of Method #2. It also works when the axis=1 arrays contain more than one item corresponding to the max value. argmax returns the first occurrence as True only, which is the behavior that works best for my problem

Answer (score 3):

Create an identity matrix and select from its rows using `argmax` on your array:

```
np.identity(a.shape[1], bool)[a.argmax(axis=1)]
# array([[False,  True],
#        [ True, False],
#        [False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Please note that this ignores ties, it just goes with the value returned by `argmax`.

Comment: `np.eye` was one *shorter* alternative, but needs `dtype=` there.

Comment: @Divakar `(a.max(1)==a.T).T` looks hard to beat in that respect.

Answer (score 2):

You're already halfway in the answer. Once you compute the *max* along an axis, you can compare it with the input array and you'll have the required binary mask!

```
In [7]: maxx = np.amax(a, axis=1)

In [8]: maxx
Out[8]: array([1, 2, 8])

In [12]: a >= maxx[:, None]
Out[12]: 
array([[False,  True],
       [ True, False],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

*Note*: This uses [NumPy broadcasting](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) when doing the comparison between `a` and `maxx`

Answer (score 0):

in on line : `np.equal(a.max(1)[:,None],a)` or `np.equal(a.max(1),a.T).T` .

But this can lead to several ones in a row.

Answer (score 0):

In a multi-dimensional case you can also use `np.indices`. Let's suppose you have an array:

```
a = np.array([[
    [0, 1, 2],
    [3, 8, 5],
    [6, 7, -1],
    [9, 5, 8]],[
    [5, 2, 8],
    [7, 6, -3],
    [-1, 2, 1],
    [3, 5, 6]]
])
```

you can access argmax values calculated for axis 0 like so:

```
k = np.zeros((2, 4, 3), np.bool)
k[a.argmax(0), ind[0], ind[1]] = 1
```

The output would be:

```
array([[[False, False, False],
        [False,  True,  True],
        [ True,  True, False],
        [ True,  True,  True]],

       [[ True,  True,  True],
        [ True, False, False],
        [False, False,  True],
        [False, False, False]]])
```