# What is wrong with my focus stacking algorithm?

Tags: python, image-processing

You can see in the final focus stacked image that the whole image is in focus. However, pieces of the image are missing and I have no clue why. The basic steps of my algorithm are:

1. Access images. Convert images to grayscale, blur the gray images a bit, then find the Laplacian of these images. I store all Laplaced images in a list.
2. Cycle through pixels in a blank image using for loops. Every iteration creates a list containing the pixel intensities of the gray, blurred, Laplaced images at that pixel value. Find the max pixel intensity. Then look at the BGR value of the ORIGINAL image where the max pixel intensity came from. Set the BGR value of the blank pixel equal to that of the max-intensity pixel.

Here is my code:

```
images = glob2.glob("Pics\\step*")  # Accesses images in the Pics folder

laps = []  # A list to contain Laplacians of images in Pics

i=0
for image in images:
    img = cv.imread(image)  # Reads image in Pics
    images[i] = img  # Bc line 6 only creates a list of image NAMES (ie strings), not actual images, this replaces string w image
    img = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Converts image to grayscale
    gauss = cv.GaussianBlur(img, (3,3), 0)  # Blurs grayed image a bit
    lap = cv.Laplacian(gauss, cv.CV_64F)  # Converts blurred, gray image to Laplacian
    lap = np.uint8(np.absolute(lap))  # Converts to Laplacian
    laps.append(lap)  # Adds Laplacian to laps
    i += 1

sample = laps[0]  # Arbitrarily accesses the first image in laps so that we can get dimensions for line 22
fs = np.zeros((sample.shape[0], sample.shape[1], 3), dtype='uint8')  # Creates a blank image with the dimensions of sample

for x in range(sample.shape[0]):  # The for loops go through every x and y value
    for y in range(sample.shape[1]):
        intensities = [laps[0][x,y], laps[1][x,y], laps[2][x,y], laps[3][x,y], laps[4][x,y], laps[5][x,y]]  # List of intensities of laplacian images
        color = images[intensities.index(max(intensities))][x,y]  # Finds BGR value of the x,y pixel in the ORIGINAL image corresponding to the highest intensity
        fs[x, y] = color  # Sets pixel of blank fs image to the color of the pixel with the strongest intensity

cv.imshow('FS', fs)
```

Here is what the code produces:

[Broken Focus Stacked Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFPY5.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please elaborate on "focus stacking algorithm"? What input does such an algorithm take and what is the expected output?

Answer (score 1):

I was inspired by your code and made this simple script, which seems to work fine. (I do not need to align images.) Using mask to select pixels in focus may be faster, but I haven't tried to compare both versions. I would appreciate any advice on how to improve it.

```
from pathlib import Path

from imageio import imread, imwrite
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from skimage.color import rgb2hsv, rgb2gray
from skimage import img_as_float, img_as_ubyte
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
from skimage.filters.rank import gradient
from skimage.morphology import disk


im_dir = Path("test")
sigma = 3

print("_____ load images _____")
fps = [f for f in im_dir.glob("*.jpg")]
print([f.name for f in fps])

images_rgb = [imread(f) for f in fps]
images_rgb_cube = np.array(images_rgb)
print("images_rgb_cube", images_rgb_cube.shape, images_rgb_cube.dtype)

print("_____ images to grey _____")
#images_grey = [rgb2hsv(im)[:,:,2] for im in ims]  #  slow
images_grey = [rgb2gray(im) for im in images_rgb]  # faster

print("_____ get gradients _____")
selection_element = disk(sigma) # matrix of n pixels with a disk shape
grads = [gradient(im, selection_element) for im in images_grey]
grads = np.array(grads)
print("grads", grads.shape, grads.dtype)

print("_____ get mask _____")
mask_grey = grads.max(axis=0, keepdims=1) == grads  # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47678252/mask-from-max-values-in-numpy-array-specific-axis
mask_rgb = np.repeat(mask_grey[:, :, :, np.newaxis], 3, axis=3)  
print("mask_rgb", mask_rgb.shape, mask_rgb.dtype)

print("_____ apply mask _____")
image_sharp = images_rgb_cube * mask_rgb
image_sharp = image_sharp.max(axis=0)
print("image_sharp", image_sharp.shape, image_sharp.dtype)

print("_____ save image _____")
imwrite(im_dir / "stacked.jpeg", image_sharp)

plt.imshow(image_sharp)
plt.show()

print("_____ save masks _____")
print("mask_grey", mask_grey.shape, mask_grey.dtype)
for i in range(mask_grey.shape[0]):
    mask = mask_grey[i]
    fp = im_dir / "{}_mask.jpeg".format(fps[i].stem)
    imwrite(fp, img_as_ubyte(mask))
    print("saved", fp, mask.shape, mask.dtype)
```